# Magento attribute dropdown values(Yes/No) prints (numeric values)

Tags: magento

I created an Attribute of type dropdown. I assigned two values of "Yes" & "No". While printing those attributes values while comparing products i get the values like "133" / "134" .
Is it because of systems predefined value or what it is ? 
How can i get the same value as i assigned for options "Yes" or "No" get printed as attribute value?

*Note* : I tried attribute type 'yes/no' , this prints '1' and '' (this will not be clear to visitors/customers).

Answer (score 0):

you can get values like this:

```
$attribute_code = 'code_of_your_attribute';
$model = Mage::getModel('customer/customer'); // if you need customer attribute
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); // if you need product attribute
$attribute = $model->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code);
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

var_dump($options);
```

if you want only yes/no:

```
$array = array();

foreach ($options as $option)
{
    if($option['label'] == "")
        continue;

    $array[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Why to change its default code? its all about backend configuration and as well other label and values are printing on a same loop. :(

Answer (score 0):

for Drop down attributes,use following code to get the text.

$_product->getAttributeText($attributeCode);